# Migrating old saves of UPBGE 0.3 to UPBGE 0.36

Tags: game-engine

I made project files on the old UPBGE 0.3 making heavy use of Logic Nodes. When I load them into the new UPBGE 0.36, the logic functions stopped working and I'm getting errors on the Python console about 'No module named bgelogic.'

How do I migrate my old UPBGE 0.3 files that makes heavy use of Logic Nodes to work with the new UPBGE 0.36?

Answer (score 1):

For projects that use Logic nodes, this is the solution I used:

1. Go to the bricks editor and disable or delete the automatically generated entry for the Logic Nodes.
2. Select the Object with the Logic Nodes applied.
3. Select the Logic node that is applied to the Object.
4. While still under the Logic node, go to Dashboard and press the Compile button. This will auto-generate a Python script.
5. Go to the Game tab and click 'Add Component'
6. Type in the component name in the following format:
   The filename of the python script without the extension 'py'
   Followed by the Logic Name.
   Example:
   If the Logic name is Cube_Control, clicking compile will generate a python script named nl_cube_control.py. The component name will be:
   nl_cube_control.Cube_Control.
   CAVEATS:
   If you used spaces and dots with your Logic name, the generated component name may be different. Review the generated script to see what name is defined under the 'Class' that contains the parameter 'PythonComponent'.

The reason it broke is because 0.36 switched from using the brick node to register the logic nodes to using the component.

If you want a clearer video explanation, please refer to this youtube video:
https://youtu.be/AXLsJKhyhYQ

If you have another method or something to add, feel free to post your answer. Thanks!

ADDENDUM:

Some nodes were changed, such as the 'Random value' suite. You will need to replace them with a new Logic node. Here's an example:

[image: old and new logic node for random value]

The upper node is from the old UPBGE 0.3, which requires a condition input. The new one no longer requires the input and will throw an error.

So far, these are the only nodes (the Random Value suite) I've encountered that were changed based on my project file made with UPBGE 0.3. If you know of other nodes, please share them here. Thanks!